# How do I make Room Database in Android Studio

Tags: database, android-studio, android-recyclerview, android-room, android-database

How do i make a local room database in Studio and add data to the database.(I don't want to let my app users to add data,I wanna add read only data. i.e,i don't want any option in user interface to add data to database )

How do i access each fields of my database table  to each items of my RecyclerView.

Comment: please show what you have done so far

Comment: https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/room